# Can I pay in shops with my iPhone 6 Plus via NFC using Apple Pay?

Tags: iphone, apple-pay

Has the "Apple Pay" service been launched yet? I have googled before asking the question but had no results.

I would like to try the technology to pay a small amount at KFC using iPhone 6 Plus.

Comment: I'm closing this since it's not specific and not general. Basically, which region in which Apple Pay is active is up to specific banks and specific point of sale vendors meeting with Apple and signing a contract with Apple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On http://www.apple.com/iphone-6/apple-pay/ it says "Coming in October".

**[UPDATE]**

Now that Apple Pay has launched, refer to [Countries and regions that support Apple Pay](https://support.apple.com/HT207957) for the most up-to-date listing of where it's supported.